# Installing node_usb_detection for Electron in Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, usb, electron, libusb

I'm trying to detect the insertion of a USB stick in Electron in Windows 10. (electron.atom.io)

I've `npm` installed `node_usb_detection` and successfully rebuilt the native `node_usb` module that it depends on.

The following line (5) in the `usb.js` file of the `node_usb` module causes an error:

```
var usb = exports = module.exports = require(binding_path);
```

The error is:

```
binding_path : C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\tmp\electron-quick-
start\node_modules\usb\src\binding\usb_bindings.node

App threw an error during load
Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\tmp\electron-quick-start\node_modules\usb\src\binding\usb_bindings.node
at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\tmp\electron-quick-start\node_modules\usb\usb.js:5:38)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\tmp\electron-quick-start\node_modules\usb\usb.js:394:3)
```

Can anyone suggest what I can do next to fix this error? It's not fun anymore!

(I had to install python2.7, SDK8.1 and vs2013 to get the `usb_bindings.node` to rebuild successfully. However, this has not fixed the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You need `electron-rebuild` https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild since Electron is very likely to use a different V8 version from the Node binary installed in your system, you have to manually specify the location of Electron's headers when building native modules and `electron-rebuild` does this for you.

```js
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

// Every time you run "npm install", run this or 
// bind it to a npm script in your package.json:
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild

// On Windows if you have trouble, try:
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

Comment: I tried that and it runs, reports Rebuild Complete and then simply DELETES my `usb_bindings.node` file, LOL! (Good Grief Charlie Brown - this just goes on and on...)

Comment: maybe it does rely on the `prebuild` then you have to add the parameter `--build-from-source` and set the env variable `npm_config_build_from_source ` to `true`. Native modules can be very tricky :P

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md may can give you a better insigh into the matter ;)

Comment: Should I expect the usb_bindings.node file to be modified by running the `electron-rebuild.cmd` ? I'm wondering if it's putting its output somewhere else. File seems unmodified after calling`electron-rebuild.cmd`.

Comment: Incidently, I'm building with `npm install --build-from-source --python=c:\Python27\python`

Comment: It should override your previous `usb_bindings.node` by running the batch since you recompile it with different headers. You could force the rebuild of a specific module via `electron-rebuild -f -w node-usb-detection` or usb-detection i am not sure which package you took since there are two :P

Comment: When I install node-usb-detection it installs node-usb as a dependency and this is what I'm trying to make work.